# Routing and State Management in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, routes, state-management

I am new to the mobile application development world. I know a little bit of React JS. In React JS we use third party packages like react-router-dom and Redux for Routing and State management.
For React Native, is there any built-in libraries or we have to use the above mentioned packages for doing those stuff. Please explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For react native I personally suggest [@react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) it's really what you gonna need for your application. it allows also to integrate with redux.

here is a sample of code, it's based on stacks and inside each stack, you can have as many as you want of screens

```
<NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {
        isReadyRef.current = true;
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name={SCREENS.HOME} component={renderTabNavigation} />
        <Stack.Screen name={SCREENS.DETAIL}>
          {(props) => <DetailScreen {...props} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Amir.  So is my understanding correct ? There is no built-in support for Routing in react-native.

Comment: Nope, there is not. react-navigation is a community solution suggested by the official react-native doc.